# SSO authentification without entering manually the credentials

Tags: apache, active-directory

I created an application witch will be used into domain and I must to make the authentification using user credentials. The user must not enter his credentials manualy.  I must somehow to take the username from the target and then to check in Active Directory and then login.

Searching over internet I found that I must to configure the Apache server

I tried installing the `mod_authnz_sspi` and then in httpd.conf entering current settings

```
<LocationMatch ^/$>
  AuthName "intranet"
  AuthType SSPI
  SSPIDomain xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  SSPIAuth on
  SSPIOfferSSPI on
  SSPIAuthoritative on
  require valid-user
  SSPIUsernameCase lower
</LocationMatch>
```

But in the browser appear to enter the username and password witch I don't want that
I also tried installing `mod_authn_ntlm` but I don't succeded
Can somebody know how to do it? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track using `mod_authnz_sspi`. Does it work if you type in the username and password? If so, then your server configuration is done.

To make the browser automatically send the credentials of the currently logged on user, the browser needs to trust the website. For IE and Chrome, you must add the website to the Trusted Sites or Intranet Sites in the Internet Options.

Firefox uses its own setting called `network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris`, which is a list of sites it trusts for authentication.

Comment: When I type username and password,  in my index.php I have written "echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'] "  and it returns the username .

Comment: That's a good start. Sounds like you just need to setup the browser to trust the website then.